# (Eclipse) JasperStudio JasperReports Server Access Configuration: AxisFault: NullPointerException

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, http-proxy

Got this error on `Repository Explorer`->`Create JasperReports Server Connection`

```
Error Details:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode:
faultString: java.lang.NullPointerException
faultActor:
faultNode:
faultDetail:
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:193)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:193)
```

although the calling the server URL, e.g. `http://somehost:8080/jasperserver/services/repository` works in the browser stating:

```
repository

Hi there, this is an AXIS service!

Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...
```

Using `JasperServer 5.2.0` and `JasperStudio 5.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may likely be due to some local HTTP proxy setup problem.

To solve this you can try the following:

- **`Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections->`**

  1. **`Provider: Manual`** (where Eclipse proxy settings are applied)
  2. (**adjust proxy rules as desired**) (try including/excluding rules matching your jasper server host)
  3. **restart Eclipse** (**important!**)

I found this solution a little hidden here: [Jasper forum question 3143 comment 16.](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/3143#comment-804603)